# jQuery Ajax Not Posting Any Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am using the Kendo UI DatePicker in a portlet.  This is my jQuery ajax code:

```
kendoWindow.find(".btnConfirm,.btnCancel").click(function(e)
        {
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass("btnConfirm"))
            {
                var strStartDate;
                var strEndDate;

                jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    url : window.urlGenerateWorkbook,
                    data :
                    {
                        strStartDate : jQuery("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(),
                        strEndDate : jQuery("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value()
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    cache : false,
                    async : true,
                    type : "POST",
                    timeout : 0,
                    success : function(jsonResponse)
                    {
                        if (jsonResponse.hasOwnProperty('ERROR'))
                        {
                            alertError(jsonResponse['ERROR']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jQuery('.pnlJournalEntry #tdEntries > div').empty();
                            setJournalEntries(strPortletID);
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(jsonResponse)
                    {

                        alertError("There was no response from the server.");

                    }
                });
            }

            kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
        }).end();
```

I am using a Kendo Window to open another window within the portlet that will ask for a date range.  It then takes those dates and sends it through ajax.  When I alert strStartDate and strEndDate, I get values.  But on the Java side, I am getting NullPointerException.  When I check the POST method in Firebug, I get nothing being posted.

Could someone please help me figure this out?  Thanks.

EDIT: I think I found the issue.  Everything in Ajax needs to be sent as a string.  The Kendo UI DatePicker, when I was setting strStartDate and strEndDate to value(), it was returning a Date.  Since Ajax can't send Dates, I had to do this:

```
data :
{
    strStartDate : jQuery('#startDate').data("kendoDatePicker").value().toString(),
    strEndDate : jQuery('#endDate').data("kendoDatePicker").value().toString()
},
```

This is now sending the following to the Java ViewController:

Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Mar 12 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

I'm still getting NullPointerException, but I think it's now on the Java side, so I am at least getting some data now.  Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Answer (score 0):

above your ajax call, try this:

```
var payload = {
    strStartDate : jQuery("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(),
    strEndDate : jQuery("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value()
};
```

and then your ajax declaration should be changed to have this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(payload),
```

Comment: This is actually posting something when I look at it in Firebug, but I am still getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **contentType**

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: Still returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: try using `"strStartDate" : jQuery("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(),
                        "strEndDate" : jQuery("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value()`